# While modelling data what is the best way to model a table that grows say 1000 times over a year for every user that is added?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

Consider a user table U and the user can upload a bunch of structured data and a obvious relation exists between the user and the data. However this table will grow almost 100x the users table. Is it a good idea to continue with this design or is there a  better alternative?

Comment: Ok I need to be more clear. There is one users table which has a one to many relationship with another table X. Now the data in this table X can grow manifold since users can upload N number of data points every day.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what you're asking? 
If I am correct you have two tables with one to many relation (`[USER TABLE] -< [DATA TABLE]`). Or do you want to have separate table for each users data.

If you have just two tables, then design is correct buth if I understood you wrong, please be more specific.

Comment: Yeah I have two tables [USER TABLE] -< [DATA TABLE] and there is a one to many relationship from the user to the data table. I was just wondering if there is any other way to model the [DATA TABLE] since it grows so fast.

Comment: Yeah this is just standard practice.

Answer (score 1):

The real question, is whether the big data should sit in SQL in the first place.

Do you need any database functionalities on that big data?

- Structured queries? Any computation on the data set, or just retrieval?
- Relational functionality beyond user-data keying?
- ACID guarantees (atomicity, consistency, isolation, durability) regarding data storage and retrieval
- Level of acceptable loss of additional data? It sounds harsh, but in one social networking site I worked on, we actually decided (and it was a sound business decision) to accept the risk that sometimes, very rarely, data would actually get *lost* - we sent it to mirrored cluster and never waited for confirmation if it actually went there.

If the answer is **no** to some of these questions, you could research NoSQL paradigms - if your model is that simple, it might just fit really well into really fast systems.

Comment: Yes, the data can be modeled following relational algebra. As of now I'm prototyping an application and using Django with its default ORM. So I'd like to stick to SQL for a while. I have been exploring redis for some parts of the data store but don't have a strong reason to move it out of RDBMS right now. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: If you're just testing out, and not approaching ~100k records, Django on default settings on a reasonable RDBMS (not sqlite) would perform fast enough. Once you hit 1M, you should start optimizing, once you hit 10M you have no choice but to optimize (HW upgrades start getting exponential), once you hit 100M you have to move to NoSQL, Map-Reduce etc (or buy mainframes).

Answer (score 0):

If its possible that there are duplicates in the upload table you may consider to use a many to many relation between these tables. When not you can use a one to many relation.